# CPU Die temperatures reaches 90° C, is that normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu, temperature

My Macbook Air 13", Mid 2011, got heated and is slow in working. I noticed that CPU Die temperature reaches 90° C, is that normal?

I've changed my fan recently but still get this issue.

[image]

Comment: I recommend installing the official [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20) more accurate readings.

Comment: What is your CPU load?

Comment: On my MBPr 2012 it can get up to the same when I do very computationally heavy tasks. I would recommend getting an external cooling pad. It can help somewhat, especially if you frequently use your computer on a soft surface like a bed cover.

Answer (score 7):

The MacBook Air 13", Mid 2011, comes with an Intel Core i5 or Core i7 ([2557M](http://ark.intel.com/products/54620/Intel-Core-i5-2557M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz), [2677M](http://ark.intel.com/products/54617/Intel-Core-i7-2677M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz)) ("Sandy Bridge") Processor and the maximum temperature allowed at the die is 100° C, per Intel's documentation on both processors.  (See TJUNCTION in the links provided.)

So while you have not yet max it out, nonetheless it shouldn't be running that hot except under considerable load. If you'er seeing that high of a temperature under an idle load then it is something to worry about.

Comment: Right now it's 92° C and I'm only using Safari with normal use, no video or audio , just browsing. how can I test it further ? may an app working in background doing this heat ?

Comment: I see my macbook air reaching 105 degree celcius, and I am siting in an air conditioned room, with cool air hitting my MacBook air directly